# CSI-2 V4L2 driver programming

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, camera, v4l2, nvidia-jetson

I am interested in porting a camera driver from one SOC(Pi) to another SOC(Jetson) which both run flavors of linux and have CSI-2 interfaces.

I have the source code for the driver. I'm trying to understand how the CSI-2 interface works with respect to V4L2. The camera is controlled by the SOC through an I2C line which control functions are provided for in the source code. What I am confused about is if I need to write something to actually pull frames from the camera and control the CSI interface directly? Or is that all standardized by the CSI-2 interface and handled by V4L2?

If you wanted to access the raw data from the camera how is this done?

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely confusing topic and extremely badly documented. Looks like proper knowledge how this works is behind closed doors of companies working on Android phones.

What I figured out so far is the following:

```
+----+    +-----+
| CS |----| CSI |---> other subdevices
+----+    +-----+
```

where CS is the camera sensor driver and CSI is the MIPI-CSI2 sensor driver that is SoC/MCU specific, usually handled together with bits of Image Signal Processor (ISP).

That was first circle of V4L2 wizardry.

Aside V4L2 there's Media Entity Framework... one of it's roles is actually link elements of the multimedia environment together in for of a graph. I'm not going into details as I still crack my head over this.

But, there are ports, endpoints and pads. Now, my understanding is first two are Open Firmware framework entities (device tree), the last one is a piece related to MEF and V4L2: a sub-device can have pads!

Each pad can either be a **source** or **sink**... or both.

Looks like endpoints in the device tree represent pads.

```
+--------+     +-------------+
|    +---|     |---+     +---|
| CS | 0 |-----| 0 | CSI | 1 |---> other pad
|    +---|     |---+     +---|
+--------+     +-------------+
```

The above diagram represents simple camera, like imx219, with one source pad logically representing CSI-2 transmitter on the physical camera linked to the sink pad of some driver handling CSI-2 receiver on the SoC/MCU.

Each of these blocks are represented by `/dev/v4l-subdevX` nodes.

That was second circle of V4L2 wizardry.

Now at this point I have my own questions I can't find answers for, but to answering one of yours: No, you don't have to implement pulling frames as long as you have a working driver for MIPI CSI-2 on your chip.

> If you wanted to access the raw data from the camera how is this done?

I don't have exact clear answer to that, but if your subdevices are linked correctly, you just open `/dev/videoX` with the right library or application (like GStreamer) and you can see the motion picture from your camera.